# ODATA4 filter to SQL where

Tags: olingo

I have created an odata service with postgrace database. I need to implement filter. For that I need to convert filter url params to jdbc where clause. Have anyone done this already?

Best Regards,
Malaka Silva

Answer (score 2):

Implementing `ExpressionVisitor` interface from Apache Olingo (based on the tag I assume you use this library) is your way to go.

I did an example app with Spring, Hibernate and Apache Olingo and used the mentioned interface for creating a HQL query. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/sollersconsulting/confitura2017/blob/master/snapgram/src/main/java/eu/sollers/odata/snapgram/processor/FilterExpressionVisitor.java) and [here](https://github.com/sollersconsulting/confitura2017/blob/master/snapgram/src/main/java/eu/sollers/odata/snapgram/domain/GenericRepository.java) and build on top of this with JDBC. App main directory: https://github.com/sollersconsulting/confitura2017/tree/master/snapgram.

Comment: Nice peace of code, olingo / odata 4 is not easy to implement. That's silly you haven't written some unit tests :-)

Comment: Yes, but it was a demo app for a conference talk :P

Comment: Yep, I'm looking to unit test my visitor. If you have time you can see my question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214601/writing-unit-test-of-expressionvisitor-with-olingo-odata-4

Comment: Arr crap, your presentation is in polish, I was curious about it :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately my English presentation about Apache Olingo was not recorded. Will check your question.

Comment: Have you got any online version of the english slides ?

Comment: Hi, I have published something here: https://github.com/sollersconsulting/jugc, but I don't think there is much about testing there.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise following the tutorials on the Olingo site they are quite good, specifically:
[Link to Olingo tutorail on $filter](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/sqo_f/tutorial_sqo_f.html)